# BLE peripheral frequently disconnected and reconnected when it connected with iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, core-bluetooth

Sometimes, my  BLE peripheral frequently  disconnected  and reconnected when it connected with my iPhone 5. Even if they were in the very close distance.  I exited my APP and restar running again, or reset my BLE peripheral , but it did not help! I must turn off my iPhone 5 and restar, then,everything became normal. I want to know why this happen and how to avoid this situation . Wait for help!